# Get just the x value from iOS Accelerometer data

Tags: swift

I'm quite new to this and really enjoying swift, I have managed to work must stuff out but this has me stumped. I want to get just the x value (a double) from my accelerometer data.

The below pulls the data and prints out :x 0.476379 y -0.849365 z -0.041885 @ 568028.476360
This is great, but I just want :0.476379 - any ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 @objc func update() {
            if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
                print(accelerometerData)

        }
 }



let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var timer: Timer!



override func viewDidLoad()
       {
           super.viewDidLoad()

       motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        }
```

Comment: Here's my guess: `accelerometerData.x`

Comment: I tried that, I get: Value of type 'CMAccelerometerData?' has no member 'x'

Comment: It's a pity there are no code examples here. I can't quite make sense of it. Maybe it's `accelerometerData.acceleration.x` or maybe it's case sensitive (Upper case X) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmacceleration

Comment: Thats it! accelerometerData.acceleration.x

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI

let accelTuple = (acceleration.x)

```
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

class Motion {

var motion = CMMotionManager()
@Published var timer = Timer()

private var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

func startAccelerometer() {
    if motion.isAccelerometerAvailable {
        self.motion.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 5
        motion.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        
        self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (10),
                           repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            
            if let data = self.motion.accelerometerData {
                let acceleration = data.acceleration
                self.accelerometerData = ("Accelerometer data : \(data)")
                print(self.accelerometerData)
                let accelTuple = (acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z)
                valuesArray.append(accelTuple)
            }
        })
        
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .default)
    }
}

func startGyroscope() {
    if motion.isGyroAvailable {
        
        self.motion.gyroUpdateInterval = 5
        motion.startGyroUpdates()
        
        self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (10),
                           repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            if let data = self.motion.gyroData {
                let x = data.rotationRate.x
                let y = data.rotationRate.y
                let z = data.rotationRate.z
                self.gyroscopeData = ("Gyroscope data : \(data)")
                print(self.gyroscopeData)
                
                let gyroTuple = (x, y, z)
                valuesArray.append(gyroTuple)
            }
        })
        
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .default)
    }
}

func startMagnetometer() {
    if motion.isMagnetometerAvailable {
        self.motion.magnetometerUpdateInterval = 5
        motion.startMagnetometerUpdates()
        
        self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (10),
                           repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            
            if let data = self.motion.magnetometerData {
                let acceleration = data.magneticField
                self.magnetometerData = ("Magnetometer data : \(data)")
                print(self.magnetometerData)
                let magneTuple = (acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z)
                valuesArray.append(magneTuple)
            }
        })
        
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .default)
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code thanks to Nick:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 @objc func update() {
                   if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData?.acceleration.x {
                print(accelerometerData)

        }
 }
```